# VBA loop to autofill a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

Been performing the keyboard to head motivation ritual trying to get this block of code to work.

What it's trying to do is create a range from cell references(numeric) and autofill the formula over one column then increment the row. This runs until i is equal to projWeeks

```
projWeeks = 36
axisRow = 46
axisCol = 5


For i = 0 To projWeeks

    axisRow = 46
    Dim tStart As Range
    Set tStart = outputSht.Cells(axisRow, axisCol)
    Dim tDest As Range
    tAxisCol = axisCol + 1
    Set tDest = outputSht.Cells(axisRow, tAxisCol)

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(tStart:tDest), Type:=xlFillDefault *///Crashes on Syntax* 


    axisRow = axisRow + 1
    Set tStart = outputSht.Cells(axisRow, axisCol)
    Set tDest = outputSht.Cells(axisRow, tAxisCol)

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(tStart:tDest), Type:=xlFillDefault

    axisRow = axisRow + 1
    Set tStart = outputSht.Cells(axisRow, axisCol)
    Set tDest = outputSht.Cells(axisRow, tAxisCol)

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(tStart:tDest), Type:=xlFillDefault

    axisRow = axisRow + 1
    Set tStart = outputSht.Cells(axisRow, axisCol)
    Set tDest = outputSht.Cells(axisRow, tAxisCol)

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(tStart:tDest), Type:=xlFillDefault

    axisCol = axisCol + 1

Next i
```

Is there another way to reference and increment cell locations to run this loop? VBA isn't my strong point to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=outputSht.Cells(axisRow, axisCol).Resize(1,2), _
                               Type:=xlFillDefault
```